# How can i add or fix my program so it loops to the start

Tags: python

I need to add a loop to my program somewhere where can I add it in\

```
def start():

#introduction
  print("Here is a quiz to test your knowledge of Pixar")
print("please enter the lower letter of the answer or it will not work")
person = input("Enter you Name:    ")
points = -50


#Q1 ask a question 
print("What year was toy story released")
answer = input("A. 1995 B. 2002 C.1999                                  = ")

# a is answer
if answer == "a":
  print ("Your Right")
  points += 11.1
else:
  print ("you need to get better")
  print ("the correct answer 1995 was ")



    #Q10  
print("What was the name of the bad guy in up")
answer = input("A. Kevin Wilson B. Charles Muntz C. Mike whiting                                  = ")

if answer == "b":
  print("that’s a righta")
  points += 78.45
  points += 0.25
else:
  print("not quite")
  print("the correct answer was Charles Muntz")



print("Well done" , person) 
print("Your final score is {}".format(points))
print("you are the best" , person)
print("I Know" , person)


if op.lower() in {'q', 'quit', 'e', 'exit'}:
    print("Goodbye!")
```

I want to add the loop so when you finish you go back to the start but I don't know how to do that could someone help me.

Comment: There are many tutorials on how to write a loop.  How did none of those help you?  Also, why is there so much code here when your problem is only how to loop through *any* code?  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.

Comment: You need a While loop or a some similar construct.  I'm not a Python programmer, but that gives you something to Google.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_loops.htm

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a **While** loop. Specifically, just inserting all your code as follows should do the job:

```
**While True:**    
.....
.....
```

I have not run your code, but I think a break statement would be needed for your final "if" statement (in order to not run endlessly), specifically:

```
if op.lower() in {'q', 'quit', 'e', 'exit'}:
    print("Goodbye!")
    break
```

Apart from those edits, I think that all the inputting and whatnot should be fine.